# How to setup integrated terminal of vs code with Cmder and bash as default

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I seem to be the very first asking this specific question.

Target:

So, I am trying to setup my development environment. I mainly use VS Code as Editor and I'd like to use Cmder as integrated shell because it looks beautiful. However, I don't really like how cmd handles things and therefore want to use Bash as default shell with Cmders theme.

What I got so far:

I am able to setup Bash as default tzask for cmder, according to this https://gist.github.com/nickautomatic/02ccb76292f7f8d9767e

[Cmder with bash as default shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IYEC.png)

I am able to setup VS Code with cmder, according to this https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration

[VS Code with Cmder as integrated shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUFL6.png)

Question:

The question remains, how can I bring this together?
...or in other words: I would like to configure VS Code with the Cmder integrated terminal starting Bash as default shell.

Comment: What do you get now and what is the problem? ConEmu creates Bash tasks automatically, I don't see much sense using cmder in your case.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What needs to come together? You have all the information there.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't intend to be unclear. I would like to have VS Code with the Cmder integrated terminal starting Bash as default shell.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/c",
    "${env:CMDER_ROOT}\\vendor\\git-for-windows\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "--login",
    "-i"
  ],
```

The `CMDER_ROOT` environment variable should point to your Cmder installation root directory.
Also, make sure you have the full version of Cmder, as the min version does not come with Git.

Comment: This is working in general but has issues if I want to startup a conda environment. Apparently related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53453487/4162265